# How to animate recyclerview in sharedElementTranistion between activities?

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, shared-element-transition

I have activity with horizontal recyclerview and in the next activity i have same items in vertical recyclerview ,how to animate items in recyclerview while changing activity 
or how can i animate the items like in gif image even in same activity while changing orientation

[image: recyclerview orientation change animation]

Answer (score 1):

First read this [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity)

and then when trying to do `RecyclerView` to `RecyclerView` transition you have to point same unique transition names in both `Activities` items lists.

To achieve that you need to set transition string on binding `ViewHolder` inside `ViewHolder` class:

```
bind() {
   ViewCompat.setTransitionName(View view, String uniqueTransitionName)
}
```

`uniqueTransitionName` should be item id, title or whatever as long as it always the same in both lists and it is not repeated.

Comment: in onBindViewHolder im setting transition name like this

        Product product = products.get(position);
        if (holder.card!=null&&Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            holder.card.setTransitionName("ima_"+product.getId());
        }

Comment: I could do the transition but i found some more problems
1-after transition  items that weren't visible in recyclerview blink in the new activity

2-items in recyclerview don't animate outside of recyclerview although i'm setting setClipChildren to false

Comment: it might be blinking because your images loaded bigger or smaller than it suppose to be also it might be because in onBind() logic if(shouldBeVisibile){makeItVisible} is missing else branch which making item notVisible